# In how many ways, we can choose two teams of mixed doubles from four couples such that if any couple participates, then it is the same team.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> In how many ways, we can choose two teams of mixed double for tennis tournament from four couples such that if any couple participates, then it is the same team.

### My approach

Case1: Each couple contributing one player. In this case, we have $2^4$ cases which can be arranged themselves in 3 ways to form two teams. Thus, *$3×2^4$* such cases.

Case2: Only couples playing. We have $4 \choose 2$ ways.

Case3: Only one couple playing. We have 4 choices to choose the couple. After that we have 6 choices to fill one spot and 4 choices for the second spot. Therefore, $4 × 6× 4$ ways.

Therefore, I get a total of 150 ways.

[But the answer is 42.](https://www.toppr.com/ask/question/in-how-many-ways-we-can-choose-two-teams-of-mixed-double-for-tennis-tournament/)

Comment: "if any couple participates, then it is the same team" : what does this mean?

Comment: @user2661923 , if an entire couple is playing, then they play as the same team. Or in other words, , if a husband and wife are playing, then they must form a team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only one part of your answer is wrong (Although I have no idea what the question itself is asking).

In case 1, you are significantly over. I think for $2^4$ you are trying to say that we have $4$ choices of $2$ each time, since we split the couples into two, and then choose $2$ arbitrarily. Unfortunately, we are playing *mixed* doubles, meaning we need $2$ men and $2$ women, and your method can result in $3$ or $4$ men or women, which is what puts you so far over.

We consider the following: select $M_1$ (man from couple 1). Then, we have 3 options left for the other man. In other words we have chosen $2$ men from $4$. Now that we have our men, we want to choose our women such that neither are in a couple with the man. This leaves $2$ women, both of whom are in a couple, and we want how many ways our of $2$ we can choose $2$, which is $2 \choose 2$. In total:
$$ {4 \choose 2} \cdot {2 \choose 2}$$
Which becomes 24. This is your only mistake. Good job otherwise!

Comment: So silly of me, I ignored the mixed doubles part! Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

The key word to this problem is these are mixed doubles, meaning one man and one woman per team. When choosing any person that’s not a part of a couple, you must restrict your options based on one man and woman. I believe you can apply your same thinking now and reach the desired solution relatively easily. Let me know if a more guided answer is desired.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out :-)